# change pandas df to python dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I would like to change the following pandas DataFrame object to a python dictionary, and then I want to get the value with `energy_emob_BB` and `energy_emob_BE`.

```
emob_energy = pd.DataFrame(session.query(abbb_emob.id,
                                         abbb_emob.scenario,
                                         abbb_emob.region,
                                         abbb_emob.energy).filter(
                           abbb_emob.scenario == 'ES2030').all())

energy_emob_BB = float(emob_energy.query('region=="BB"')['energy'])
energy_emob_BE = float(emob_energy.query('region=="BE"')['energy'])
```

Here is some output of the DataFrame and 2 objects which I have to get from the DataFrame

```
(Pdb) emob_energy
   id scenario region     energy
0   1   ES2030     BB  2183000.0
1   2   ES2030     BE  1298333.0

(Pdb) energy_emob_BB
2183000.0

(Pdb) energy_emob_BE
1298333.0
```

How would I make .query to work with python dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` renders the data a dicts in dicts by default.

```
df_dict = emob_energy.to_dict()
print(df_dict['energy_emob_bb']) # {0: 2183000.0, 1: 1298333.0, ...}
```

If you want them as dict of lists:

```
df_dict = emob_energy.to_dict(orient='list')
```

Comment: can you actually create the dict without creating the dataframe?

Comment: Of course! But I don't know how without seeing your data. If I responded to your original question then mark it as answered please.